# Constraint Validation Bubbles Gone In Opera 16 on OS X

Tags: html, opera

In Opera 16, the constraint validation bubbles no longer display. This can be recreated on the simplest of examples, compare what happens here in Opera and Chrome:

```
<form>
    <input required>
    <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/7qPRm/

Since Opera is now Blink based, it should inherit Chrome's exact implementation, but this issue is not present in Chrome. Anybody know what's up?

**Edit: This appears to be OS X only. Things seem fine on Windows.**

Comment: Just because they are both using blink, doesn't mean they are always using the exact same version, also both contain custom, non-chromium code too, ie they don't necessarily share the same behavior. That being said, it's working fine for me with Opera 17(.0.1241.45)

Comment: @ndm Is that on OS X? I just noticed that this is working fine on Windows.

Comment: Both, OS X and Windows, though OS X is an old 10.6.3 running in a VM, I haven't updated it ever since I've stopped developing for mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Opera 16 that was fixed in Opera 17.